# Breakpoints won't hit on CLion

Tags: c++, clion

CLion gives the following hover message accompanied with a "no" sign instead of a breakpoint red dot:

```
This breakpoint will currently not hit. No executable code associated with the following line.
```

This also happens when I put a breakpoint on a print statement. The print statement does get printed in the std output. How can the line not be associated with executable code then?

Comment: If you set a breakpoint earlier in the same function (one that will definitely be hit) and then step through the code statement by statement until you get to the part where you fail to set the breakpoint, does it work?

Comment: is that code scoped in a sort of boolean condition or after a return statement?

Answer (score 1):

This most likely means that the code is optimized out and will not be included in the executable you are running.

The breakpoint validation is a [recent feature](https://blog.jetbrains.com/clion/2019/07/clion-2019-2-has-landed/#debugger).

Answer (score 0):

I'm on macOS, for me, the fix was to change the Generator option, which, in turn, generates the CMake options as follows
[image]